# How to pass a Int** between C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, managed

I have a C++ Dll, which I can't modify and I need to use it with my C# code. So I created a C++/CLI class as my wrapper for the original C++ class.

There is a method with a int** argument and I don't know how to pass it to the C++/CLI code and then to the C# code.

Here is the definition of the native C++ method which returns the number of elements in the frame:

```
int Precursor::GetFrame(int **frame, int id)
```

Could you help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When importing the C++ DLL you need to marshal the pointer-to-pointer `int **frame` as `ref IntPtr ppFrame`.  Your CLI function will use `IntPtr% frame`.

Comment: I have found another way in fact, I used the same definition for my C++/CLI method and in the C# method I created a temporary int* which I pass to the method and then I copied each value to a int[] which was passed by ref.

Answer (score 0):

use marshaling refer below link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66244/Marshaling-with-C-Chapter-2-Marshaling-Simple-Type